# Difference between Primefaces and primefaces mobile

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

My goal is to develop a system accessible through both Desktop Browsers and Mobiles. Primefaces is what I have settled on(Although this can change if someone has a better suggestion). Anyway I have been looking up the difference between primefaces and primefaces mobile and it seems there is not much of one. The best discussion I could find was http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=23193. Otherwise my googling skills are letting me down or there is just not that much information on it.

Otherwise it seems you should just know the difference between them. I, sadly, do not know.Although this may seem simple to many of you I just finished college about 3 months ago and have been using php with the yii framework since then so this switch is a huge undertaking to me, I have no experience in anything like it. So I am turning to you guys for help. Could someone explain if there is a bigger difference between the 2 other then primefaces mobile being optimised for small screens. This makes it sound that if I program in just primefaces it will display in both browsers and Mobiles but there could be CSS issues with mobiles.

Could this be avoided by finding out if the user is using a desktop or mobile and just switching to a different CSS file or is this plain ridiculous? Would I require 2 seperate pages for both the desktop and the mobile version? If I do would you be able to provide a very basic example of the difference between the code please? Does anyone know a good tutorial that highlights the difference between both and shows you some examples?

Thanks for any help provided. It is greatly appreciated.

Further Info: I am using Eclipse indigo with Maven, JSF, Jboss and Primefaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Could this be avoided by finding out if the user is using a desktop or mobile and just switching to a different CSS file or is this plain ridiculous?`

You are getting confused over Responsive web design and having dedicated mobile page for your site. With Responsive web design approach, we make use of flexible and fluid layouts with the help of Media queries to adapt to almost any screen size, that way you do not need to have a  particular mobile version site for your existing site. On other hand, when you have a dedicated mobile site, user device is detected and and routed to appropriate desktop/mobile site. And this is often a debate in regards to UX whether a dedicated mobile site is required or not, it depends upon which approach you take.

See also:

- http://boagworld.com/mobile-web/separate-mobile-site-vs-responsive-design/

`Would I require 2 seperate pages for both the desktop and the mobile version?`

As mentioned above it is the approach you take. Primefaces Mobile is based on jQuery Mobile which helps in creating standalone mobile sites that usually have stripped down important content when compared to a normal desktop site that are compatible with wide variety of devices.

See also:

- http://goodchee.com/blog/the-mobile-web-responsive-design-or-jquery-mobile/

`If I do would you be able to provide a very basic example of the difference between the code please?`

From code prespective, you can see the code on primefaces showcase but I guess you need not compare code, you need to compare the features that both differ. Here is a site [separate-mobile-responsive-website-presidential-smackdown](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/22/separate-mobile-responsive-website-presidential-smackdown/) that compares a desktop version with a mobile version.

`Does anyone know a good tutorial that highlights the difference between both and shows you some examples?`

Look at the site in the above answer, it has a lot to explain.

See also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx